# How to set MAX vaalue of a SeekBar in XML file?

Tags: android, xml, android-mediaplayer, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am making a Music Playe app and I am using a custom Circular seekbar made by 
And it's `max` value is defined in the XML file

```
        <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/musicSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:max="100"/>
```

Now, I want to assign the `max` value of the SeekBar to the total duration of the media file , but the function `Seekbar.setMax(int)` doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead calculate the progress based on the duration and set that progress. Let the max be 100 and so we can get the progress percentage by getting

```
x= (current_played_time)*100/ (total_time)
```

and

```
seekbar.setProgress(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

set the `android:max` property in the xml (`app:max` should be `android:max`).